# Constitutive mutation in operator gene

Tags: gene-expression, mutations, operons

If a constitutive mutation happens in the operator of an inducible operon, does that mean that repressors won't be able to bind them ? Or does it mean that even if repressors are bound, they will not have any effect on the gene ?

I am specifically talking about lac operon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lac operon there are two possibilities for constitutive expression mutations:

1. The operator is never closed.

Reason: Mutation of the repressor, so its not present, doesn't bind or binds only with very low affinity for the operon.

1. The repressor can not bind.

Reason: The binding site for the repressor is mutated.

See this [Website](http://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~mcclean/plsc431/prokaryo/prokaryo2.htm) or this [Website](http://learning.covcollege.ac.uk/content/Jorum/GMB_Gene-organisation-regulation_LM-1.2/page73.htm) for more information.

Comment: What is the meaning of "the operator is never closed" ?

Comment: I have expanded my answer.